# How to add a new node to root node in XML document using Libxml2 that should be first element

Tags: libxml2

I am using Libxml2 Every time i am adding new nodes to the existing XML document. Adding new nodes is fine but what ever i added nodes in the XML document it added last of the child node but i want to add new nodes after the root node.

Comment: How are you adding nodes? Which child node do you mean when you say "it added last of the child node"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your new node, you can get use [xmlAddPrevSibling](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlAddPrevSibling) on the current first child of the root to get your new node inserted "before" the current first child.